# Prestashop 1.6 > Get all tags or get tag by name

Tags: list, tags, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to get tag id's from prestashop, but TagsCore does not provide list of all tags and either does not contain method to get tag by name? Is it possible without writing custom function somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TagCore you have the construct:

```
public function __construct($id = null, $name = null, $id_lang = null)
{
    $this->def = Tag::getDefinition($this);
    $this->setDefinitionRetrocompatibility();

    if ($id) {
        parent::__construct($id);
    } elseif ($name && Validate::isGenericName($name) && $id_lang && Validate::isUnsignedId($id_lang)) {
        $row = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getRow('
        SELECT *
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'tag` t
        WHERE `name` = \''.pSQL($name).'\' AND `id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang);

        if ($row) {
            $this->id = (int)$row['id_tag'];
            $this->id_lang = (int)$row['id_lang'];
            $this->name = $row['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

So, if you call:

```
$tag = new Tag(null, "stringtag", $id_lang);
if($tag->id !== null){
    // stringtag exists for that id_lang
}
```

But there is no method for getting a list/collection of all the tags. But a simple query like:

```
Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'tag`')
```

or

```
Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'tag` WHERE `id_lang`='.$id_lang)
```

is simple enough to get the array with all the tags.